# "This page can’t be displayed"?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

Why SharePoint page often goes "This page can’t be displayed" in regular interval and come up after 5 min automatically. But working fine when i open in server. How to rectify this issue?

Comment: Can you provide details of error.(Screenshot or Log file)

Comment: Please describe how you use SharePoint when the issue occurs, SharePoint farm architecture, what SharePoint this is (2010, 2013, Online), etc.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like intermittent communication issues between the client and the server.

When the client PC sees 'this page cannot be displayed', have you done any checks to see whether the client PC can ping the SharePoint server, or resolve the server over the network? If not, that would be the first place I'd start. Can the client PC see other sites on the same network at the time you're having issues with SharePoint?

Is this a remote site? Is the client PC on the same network?

Andy

Comment: From Client PC, server is pinging. And PC on the same network only. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried from another PC at the same time? We need to work out whether it's an issue with a single client PC, or with the server. If we see the error on all client PCs at the same time, then it's likely to be the server, if it's only a single PC that's having an issue, then it's a problem with that PC.